# PDAL Filter output is same as input file

Tags: python, filter, las, point-cloud, pdal

I've applied SOR filter using PDAL python.Below is the code snippet of the same,

```
json =  
 """  
{  
  "pipeline":[  
    "D:/Lidar_collect_3/output/output_1.las",  
    {  
      "type":"filters.outlier",  
      "method":"statistical",  
      "mean_k":6,  
      "multiplier":1.0  
    },  
    "D:/Lidar_collect_3/output/output.las"  
  ]  
}  
"""  

pipeline = pdal.Pipeline(json)  
pipeline.validate()  
pipeline.execute()
```

The output.las created has the same number of points as input(looks same as the input). I've tried with different mean_k and multiplier values, but no result.

Where did I go wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your json is being interpreted as a string rather than as a json object.
Try importing the json library (part of the standard Python library) and then loading the string as a json object. For example:

```
import json
json_string = """  
{  
  "pipeline":[  
    "D:/Lidar_collect_3/output/output_1.las",  
    {  
      "type":"filters.outlier",  
      "method":"statistical",  
      "mean_k":6,  
      "multiplier":1.0  
    },  
    "D:/Lidar_collect_3/output/output.las"  
  ]  
}  
"""  

json_pipeline = json.loads(json_string)
pipeline = pdal.Pipeline(json_pipeline)  
pipeline.validate()  
pipeline.execute()
```